# java library that can make zigzag edges to an image

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm interested if there's a library in java that can cut an image(transparent PNG) edges in zigzag shape.

There are hundreds of photoshop tutorials but I'm interested in building an automated solution.
here is a sample:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a thousand ways you could do this in java.

One way would be to make a resizable border as an SVG, then pull your target image into it with a filter effect.

There are lots of SVG tools for java, one possiblity is Batik: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/